# How to use web3.storage in-place of Infura as IPFS for my NFT Marketplace?

Tags: web3js, javascript, nft, web3.py, infura

I wanted to use Infura as my IPFS for a project, but now as it has been deprecated, I got a suggestion to use web3.storage instead. But I couldn't find any useful tutorials for using it in my project. The base of my project is related to the Nader Dabit tutorial for NFT Marketplace. Infura generating random fetch addresses is causing my project to crash. I am able to create an NFT and after signing it from Metamask, it crashes with an "Axios Error" everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infura Public IPFS has been deprecated and there are many other ways to upload the file in IPFS.

1. You can use Local IPFS to upload to IPFS.
2. You can use Web3.storage: https://web3.storage/docs/how-tos/store